# Closed form of $ \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}2^k k^m$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

Is there a closed form of the above equation or something that simplifies it? Here is the same equation copied:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}2^k k^m$$

It looks very similar to the Stirling number of the 2nd kind but slightly modified, which looks like this:

$$S(m,n)=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k} k^m$$

Comment: Are you sure the formula has $2^k$ inside summation ?

Comment: I managed to find the generating function: $$\frac{1}{x+1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2x}{1+x}\right)^kk^m.$$ This can be found using the identity $$\sum_{k\geq j} \binom{k}{j}x^k = x^j(1-x)^{-j-1}.$$ I am not sure if there is going to be a pretty closed form solution for the general $m$.

Comment: If we take the exponential generating function (e.g.f.) over $m$, we get $(2e^z-1)^n=(2(e^z-1)+1)^n$. Since $(e^z-1)^n$ is the e.g.f. of $n!S(m,n)$, we can use that to rewrite your sum as $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}2^k k!S(m,k).$$ It's still not a closed form, but at least all the summands are now nonnegative. We can also rewrite this without the $2$'s in the sum if we express the e.g.f. as $(e^z+(e^z-1))^n$. It won't make the sum easier, though.

Answer (score 1):

For each fixed $m$ this sum is [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function), and so computers can solve for a closed form (or tell us that none exists). You can read more in the excellent book [$A=B$](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.html), which the authors have made freely available at that link.

Now we can start solving these for fixed values of $m$ (by asking [sage](https://sagemath.org), say) and we get

$$
\begin{array}{|c|l|}
\hline
m & S(m) \\
\hline
1 & 2 \, n\\
\hline
2 & 4 \, n^{2} - 2 \, n\\
\hline
3 & 8 \, n^{3} - 12 \, n^{2} + 6 \, n\\
\hline
4 & 16 \, n^{4} - 48 \, n^{3} + 60 \, n^{2} - 26 \, n\\
\hline
5 & 32 \, n^{5} - 160 \, n^{4} + 360 \, n^{3} - 380 \, n^{2} + 150 \, n\\
\hline
\vdots & \vdots \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

It's not hard to see that $S(m) = (2n)^m + O(n^{m-1})$, and the OEIS lets us push this slightly further. Indeed, the sequence of second order terms, $2,12,48,160,\ldots$ seems to be [A001815](https://oeis.org/A001815), which tells us that (probably -- I haven't tried to prove this)

$$S(m) = 2^m n^m - 2^{m-2} m (m-1) n^{m-1} + O(n^{m-2})$$

You can also look at the sequence of linear terms $2,-2,6,-26,150,\ldots$, which is (up to sign) [A076726](https://oeis.org/A076726). Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have a nice closed form in terms of $m$.
You can probably push this farther with some effort, but naively neither the sequence of third terms $6,60,360,1680,6720\ldots$ or the sequence of quadratic terms $4,-12,60,-380,2940,\ldots$ is in the OEIS.
Because of this (and the lack of closed form for the linear terms), my guess is that getting a closed form parameterized by $m$ is going to be quite hard, if it's possible at all. Thankfully, for lots of purposes being able to get a closed form for each fixed $m$ is good enough!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting with the [Pochhammer symbol](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Pochhammer&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22Pochhammer%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22SloppyFunction%22%7D):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}x^k k^m= (-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(2)_{k-1}^m}{(1)_{k-1}^m}\binom{n}{k}(-x)^k $$

helps [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28-1%29%5E%28n-k%29+*binom%28n%2Ck%29+*2%5Ek+%28pochhammer%28a%2Ck-1%29%2Fpochhammer%281%2Ck-1%29%29%5E7%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Cn%7D%5D) use the [hypergeometric function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=hypergeometricpfq):

$$\boxed{\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}x^k k^m=-(-1)^nxn\,_{m+1}\operatorname F_m(2,\dots,2,1-n;1,\dots 1,2;x),m\in\Bbb N}$$

with $m$ “$2$”s and $m-1$ “$1$”s. Also applying a [$\binom n k$ integral representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+representation+binom%28n%2Ck%29), valid for the variable ranges in the sum, [uses](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28-1%29%5E%28n-k%29+catalan%5Ek+k%5Em+E%5E%28-I+k+t%29+%281+%2B+E%5E%28I+t%29%29%5En%2F%282+Pi%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Cinfty%7D%5D) the [polylogarithm $\operatorname{Li}_v(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Polylog%5Bv%2Cx%5D) and [Lerch transcendent $\Phi(z,s,a)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Lerch+transcendent):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}x^k k^m=\frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi (e^{it}+1)^n\left(\operatorname{Li}_{-m}\left(-x e^{-i t}\right)-(-x e^{-i t})^{n+1}\Phi\left(-x e^{-i t},-m,n+1\right)\right)dt$$

Comment: There should be a way to use the binomial coefficient to convert the finite sum into an infinite one and use the definition of the hypergeometric function

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the $2$ does not hide simpler thing (*may be* simpler to analyze).

Considering instead
$$S(m,n,x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n-k}\,\binom{n}{k}\,x^k\, k^m$$ for $m>0$ we have
$$S(m,n,x)=n\,x\,(x-1)^{n-m}\,T(m,y,x)\qquad \text{with} \qquad y=n x$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & y-1 \\
 3 & y^2-3 y+(x+1)\\
 4 & y^3-6 y^2+(4 x+7) y-\left(x^2+4x+1)\right) \\
 5 & y^4-10 y^3+(10 x+25) y^2-\left(5 x^2+30 x+15\right)
   y+\left(x^3+11 x^2+11x+1\right)\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

We seek to simplify

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} {n\choose k} 2^k k^m.$$

This is

$$m! [z^m] \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} {n\choose k} 2^k \exp(kz)
\\ = m! [z^m] (-1+2\exp(z))^n
= m! [z^m] (1+2(\exp(z)-1))^n
\\ = m! [z^m] \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} 2^q (\exp(z)-1)^q
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} 2^q q! {m\brace q}.$$

Now note that when $n\gt m$ we may lower the  upper range to $m$ because
the Stirling number is zero on the omitted  values. On the other hand
when $n\lt m$ we may raise to $m$ because the  binomial coefficient is
zero in the added range. We finally obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sum_{q=0}^m n^{\underline{q}} 2^q {m\brace q}.}$$

For example with $m=3$ we find

$$n^{\underline{0}} 2^0 {3\brace 0}
+ n^{\underline{1}} 2^1 {3\brace 1}
+ n^{\underline{2}} 2^2 {3\brace 2}
+ n^{\underline{3}} 2^3 {3\brace 3}
\\ = 0 + 2n + 12n(n-1) + 8n(n-1)(n-2)
\\ =  8 n^3  - 12 n^2  + 6 n.$$

We have with $m=4$

$$n^{\underline{0}} 2^0 {4\brace 0}
+ n^{\underline{1}} 2^1 {4\brace 1}
+ n^{\underline{2}} 2^2 {4\brace 2}
+ n^{\underline{3}} 2^3 {4\brace 3}
+ n^{\underline{4}} 2^4 {4\brace 4}
\\ = 0 + 2n + 28n(n-1) + 48n(n-1)(n-2) + 16n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)
\\ =   16 n^4  - 48 n^3  + 60 n^2  - 26 n.$$

This computation was suggested in the comments and the other answers.
It goes through with $m=0$ as well.